# FTP app that can monitor a local folder

Tags: software-recommendation, data-synchronization, ftp

I recently switched to another text editor from Coda. The feature I miss most from Coda is that it can monitor any folder and publish any changes made with a click of a button. I have been looking for an FTP application that offers this functionality, but haven't found anything. Most apps will "synchronise" a remote and a local folder by scanning them and looking at the size and/or timestamp of each file. Since many of my projects contain thousands of projects and I'm on a slow connection, this is not a good solution for me. So I'm looking for an app that can:

- Monitor files in a local folder (don't care about remote changes)
- "Mark" these when they are changed
- Offer to upload the files that have been changed since the last upload

I only need to watch for local changes. I am the only one editing these files. So I can safely overwrite anything on the server when it has been changed locally.

I can not use Git or any versioning protocol because most projects are running on cheap shared hosting, without shell access. However I am fairly experienced using the shell so if there's a solution there that's also an option, although I would prefer an app with a GUI.

Comment: What do you mean about "Mark"?

Comment: Ah. I called it that for lack of a better word. The app should simply remember the files that have changed, so I can upload them later when it's convenient for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Weex](http://weex.sourceforge.net/) for uploading only the files that have changed since last time Weex was run. Neat little tool that can be run from scripts.

I have tried a couple of GUI ftp apps, but haven't haven't come across any GUI tools that can do the same.

Comment: After some more research there doesn't seem to be an app capable of this function (too bad, I would probably buy it for that function alone). So I suppose your solution comes closest! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Transmit can achieve what you're looking for thanks to its Transmit Disk feature.

Once you have specified a remote location as a favorite (analogous to bookmarking it), you can use Transmit Disk to create a local volume with the same name as the favorite. Any changes made to this volume's files are mirrored to the server. The two are kept in constant sync.

According to Panic's website (and my own usage), the files are uploaded even if Transmit.app itself isn't running. Transmit Disk runs as a separate background process. On my system, with one volume mounted and shortly after requiring a sync, this process is using 0% CPU and 13MB of memory. Performance, it seems, is not an issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few commercial FTP programs that offer Local/Remote folder synchronisation, here are a few that I know of.

[Captain FTP](http://www.xdsnet.net/captain_ftp/)

**Folder Synchronization**

Synchronize or mirror entire folders/directories between local and remote sites in either direction through the Visual Browser Module.

~~~~

[Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/)

**Sync**

Panic's Transmit, my current client of choice, has a function called Sync which basically lets you pick two folders and sync their contents.

Comment: I have looked into most of these apps. The problem is that the synchronisation works by scanning the contents of both the local and the remote folder, and that usually takes a LONG time when working with 1000s of files remotely. I'd rather skip the "comparison" of files, and just upload any files that have been changed locally since the last synchronisation, just like Coda does it!

Comment: Since Coda is by the same people who write Transmit (and the FTP capabilities in Coda ARE taken from Transmit), there's a good possibility that Sync works in the same fashion.

Comment: It doesn't. I've tried. :/

Answer (score 0):

I think http://www.yummysoftware.com/features/ftp-watcher does what you're looking for? It even has the 'Mark' function equivalent (by archiving the files).